# C++ error Undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

I cant solve it... Help Please

projects\intento2\intento2\as.cpp(128): error C2065: 'Generate' : undeclared identifier

```
    mov ecx,[ebp+32]
    mov edx,[ebp+28]
    PUSHAD;


 if (Generate)
{
 GenerateTexture(pDevice, &texGreen , D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255,0,255,0));
 Generate = false;
}
```

Comment: Is `Generate` a name of a class?

Comment: Post code that isn't all truncated and weird looking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an 'undeclared identifier' error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030/what-is-an-undeclared-identifier-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the compiler is complaining that no symbol `Generate` exists at the point where you're trying to use it.

It could be any number of things, such as:

- misspelling the name;
- having it declared inside an inactive `#ifdef`;
- not including the header file where it's declared; or
- a dozen other possibilities.

We can't actually tell from the code you've posted how (or if) you've defined it so you'll have to go and find that first. Once you find and post that (or create it if you've neglected to do so), we should be able to help further.